# How to modify this function so it stacks the arches right in front of the camera?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, aframe

I created a function that stacks arches side by side in front of a camera:

```
<!-- HTML -->

<a-curvedimage
  v-for="(value, index) in model"
  :theta-length="42"
  :rotation="setThumbsRotation(value, index)">
</a-curvedimage>
<a-camera
  ref="camera"
  rotation="0 -90 0">
</a-camera>

// JS

// value is not being used and index goes like 0, 1, 2, etc.
setThumbsRotation (value, index) {
  const thumbLength = 42
  const rotationY = 189 - thumbLength * 21 + index * thumbLength
  return `0 ${rotationY} 0`
}
```

[image]

But as you can see, they're not exactly in front of the camera. How to modify `setThumbsRotation` to achieve this?

[image]

And **regardless** of the number of arches:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need set rotation one by one, I recommend wrap all images in an entity, and only set the wrapper rotation once.

`` //theta is sum of all images theta-length
setThumbsRotation (theta) {
  const rotationY = 180 - (theta / 2)
  return `0 ${rotationY} 0`
} ``

Comment: But if I don't set the rotation of the curved images, they'll all stack on top of another.

Comment: you could set `theta-start` and `theta-length`, the default 'theta-start' is 0, for example, if you want to have to connected curved images, you could set `theta-start=0 theta-length=74` on image1, and `theta-start=74 theta-length=74` on image2.